# textbox_tapped event not firing in metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am building a win 8 app which has a textbox control inside a hierarchy of elements like ScrollViewer->Stackpanel->Grid->Image & TextBox. The textBox contain a tapped event to navigate to a page. This textbox_tapped event is not at all firing. I am not getting any error or exceptions also. Can somebody tell me the solution for getting this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something to do with the fact that you are testing it on a normal PC with a mouse, so its not a tap, though I'm not sure about that. You might get a similar result by using the "GotFocus" event instead.